Api platform automatically set example value for iri-reference
I have some DTO's where the post body looks like this:
{
  "course": "https://example.com/",
  "category": "https://example.com/",
  "content": "string",
  "anonymous": true
}

Here, the fields "course" and "category" refer to other DTO's. I want the example value to be automatically set to the correct path, e.g. "course": "/api/courses/1",
I know I can set it manually for every endpoint, but I was looking for a way to set this for all endpoints that use an iri-reference.
The json.openapi for this DTO looks like this:
"Course.Comment.jsonld": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "",
        "deprecated": false,
        "properties": {
          "@context": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "@vocab": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "hydra": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                      "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "@vocab",
                  "hydra"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": true
              }
            ]
          },
          "@id": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "@type": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "course": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ],
            "format": "iri-reference",
            "example": "https://example.com/"
          },
          "category": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ],
            "format": "iri-reference",
            "example": "https://example.com/"
          },
          "content": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ]
          },
          "anonymous": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "creator": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ],
            "format": "iri-reference",
            "example": "https://example.com/"
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "content"
        ]
      },

